# fetch from mysql tabel with angular js using $http

Tags: php, jquery, angularjs, ajax

hi i am new to angular js ,i want to fetch mysql data from tabel this is my controller define in finalOrder.js file i have also include my tst.php file with this code.the problem is that its not returning any value.
please help me with this coding ,thank you in advance.

```
 (function(){

 angular
      .module('ecoms')
      .controller('finalOrder',finalControler);

      function finalControler ($http){

        var vm = this;

 vm.value1 = 'one';
 vm.value2 = 'two';

        vm.testfun = testfun;

        function testfun($http){alert("in controller");
      $http.get("tst.php")
      .success(function(data){

          alert(data);
        });
      // var chkval2 = document.getElementById('rad1').value;

       if (document.getElementById('r1').checked) {
  var chkval1 = document.getElementById('r1').value;
}
    if (document.getElementById('r2').checked) {
  var chkval1 = document.getElementById('r2').value;
}
            //alert(chkval1);
          switch (chkval1) {
        case 'one':

        alert(chkval1);

            break;
        case 'two':
            alert(chkval1);
            break;


    }
      }
  }

})();
```

**and this is my tst.php file**

```
include("db_config.php");
 $query = $db->query("SELECT *  FROM customer_shipping where Customer_ID=1");

 $output = array();
        if($query->num_rows > 0){ 
            while($row = $query->fetch_assoc()){
              $output[] = $row;
             } 

echo json_decode($output);   
         }
?>
```

Comment: use `echo json_encode($output);` instead of `echo json_decode($output);`

Comment: done but nothing showing up

Comment: the function only execute till alert("in controller"); after that i dont know if the program is runing or not

Comment: add an error handler to the http.get and see what caused the error

Comment: how can i do that

Comment: @sagarrokade `$http.get('tst.php').then((res) => {console.log(res)}, (err)=>{console.log(err)})`

Comment: so i founf that i am using "this" method in my controller and $http have to passed with $scope is this an issue